# Set Skype for Business PIN for all users

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business-2016

I know that the PowerShell command to set a single user's Skype for Business PIN is this:

```
Set-CsClientPin -Identity "User Name" -Pin 123456
```

This page seems to help:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398929.aspx

However, I can't figure out how to set the PIN for all users with `“Audio_Video_Dialin_Conferencing”` to 123456

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a per-user "Audio_Video_Dialin_Conferencing" setting within Skype for Business, other than using separate client/conferencing policies for users. However, if you're looking to set all user PINs to 123456, the following would allow you to do so:

```
Get-CsUser | Set-CsClientPin -Pin 123456
```